# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

hii bascally i find a issue in a php script when i am installing that script everything is fine
on last step where i have to import demo content there i see this error

```
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `languages`
 (`id`, `name`, `code`, `default`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (3, English, en, 1, 2022-05-21 14:02:42, 2022-05-21 14:02:42))
```

now i dont k now why it shappening if any expert is ther eplease let me knwo how to fic this issue
here i the my website link
https://webtools.wehavebest.com/

website is working fine but on last step it sshowing error
[basic error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLp6G.png)

```
Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback
```

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:703

```
 * @throws \Illuminate\Database\QueryException

 */

protected function runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)

{

    // To execute the statement, we'll simply call the callback, which will actually

    // run the SQL against the PDO connection. Then we can calculate the time it

    // took to execute and log the query SQL, bindings and time in our memory.

    try {

        return $callback($query, $bindings);

    }



    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error

    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a

    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.

    catch (Exception $e) {

        throw new QueryException(

            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e

        );

    }

}



/**

 * Log a query in the connection's query log.

 *

 * @param  string  $query

 * @param  array  $bindings

 * @param  float|null  $time

 * @return void

 */

public function logQuery($query, $bindings, $time = null)

{
```

above code is the error which i sshowing by debugger

Comment: i am watching this code with the help of debugger

Answer (score 0):

Check the data in your table `languages`. It seems like there have been a record with `id=3`.
If you're sure there's no the same data, you can set the column `id`  `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Then don't care about `id` when you insert data to the table.I mean you can skip the `id` column.

Comment: its showing me error in this file
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:703

Comment: Yes, but the error occured in the database layer.

Comment: i didnt understand how to change the code

Comment: according to error this is the code line where error is coming


catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new QueryException(
                $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
let m eknow what to cahnge